# Can I update application credentials through Amazon SNS API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, certificate, apple-push-notifications

Oddly enough when I go through the documentation for SNS, I see the method to [create an application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#createPlatformApplication-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.CreatePlatformApplicationRequest-), but no method to update credentials on an application. When a year has gone by since some certificate was renewed, how can you re-upload the new p12 without going to the web interface, Applications, searching, selecting, and choosing "Update credentials" under the actions menu?

Comment: What credentials do you intent to update in the application?

Comment: @error2007s Just replace the p12 file with the new exported renewed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions, the console uses the same underlying APIs as the SDKs, so there's almost always a way.

The p12 file you speak of appears to be the credentials SNS uses to authenticate itself to the underlying messaging provider when acting on your behalf, and it looks as if these can be modified with [`SetPlatformApplicationAttributes` in the query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetPlatformApplicationAttributes.html), and in your case [SetPlatformApplicationAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#setPlatformApplicationAttributes-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.SetPlatformApplicationAttributesRequest-).

Of course, you have to split the file into public key (certificate) and secret (private key), first.